# What is the meaning of "host crossdomain.xml from port 843"?

Tags: apache-flex, sockets, crossdomain.xml

How is a file hosted on one particular port vs another port?  In order to get my flex program to do anything, even on localhost, I apparently have to accomplish this, but although I know how to FTP my crossdomain.xml to my GoDaddy server, I don't even begin to understand the meaning of hosting it on port 843.  I don't even know where to start.  Can anybody here even get my foot in the door?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What kind of services are you interacting with?  Is the port number being hard-coded somewhere in your Flex application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that you need to create a website that listens to that port, and then serve the file from that website.

Comment: The way that I create a "website" is by uploading html and php to my server, how do I control what "port" that is "served" from?

Comment: That is not creating a website.  That is uploading content to an existing website.  Since you are talking about a hosting company, I think they are the best resource for this.

Comment: Well how would I go about doing it on localhost for example?

Comment: it depends on your system.  If you're running windows server, and IIS, then you can create a new website, and specify the port in the properties window.  I'm not sure how to do it in Linux.

Comment: Using Apache, add `Listen 843` to `httpd.conf`.